# Maya: Get name of all nodes created by script

Tags: list, nodes, maya

I was wondering if there’s a way to get the name of any new node every time a new node is created. I’d like to compile a list of all the nodes created by my script so they can be cleanly deleted all at once if needed.

*Edit - A better solution would be if I can get to the name of all the new nodes in the scene after the script is done executing. This way if my script renames a new node while executing, the correct name will be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `scriptJob` and listen for the `DagObjectCreated` event:
http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/scriptJob.html

However, unless your script is calling external dependencies that you have little/no control over the output from, I think you'd be much better off simply recording the actions your script is taking. And if necessary, persisting this data as `JSON` or similar to use between sessions or modules.

**Edit**:
As per comments, to detect created or modified non-dag objects it may be more useful to list scene contents with `cmds.ls()`: http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/ls.html

Eg:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

before = cmds.ls()
cmds.polySphere()
cmds.polyCube()
after = cmds.ls()

diff = set(before).symmetric_difference(set(after))
print(diff)
```

Comment: The script creates some non-DAG objects so script job won’t give me quite the functionality I’m looking for. I’m not sure how I’d go about your second suggestion though it does sound like a viable solution. Is it possible to compare the scene before and after the script is executed to pick up any new nodes? (This would also work better as the script does rename some nodes after creating them)

Comment: You can list all scene content with a straight up `cmds.ls()` command. Does that suit your purpose?

Comment: This should get the job done. Thanks for suggestions!